# How to have diffrent backgrond colors in semilogx plot?

Tags: matlab

I want to have my semilogx plot with 3 different colors. e.g. between 20Hz to 10KHz: Green, between 10KHz to 100KHz: Blue and between 100KHz to 1MHz: Red.

```
semilogx(freq,20*log10(abs(HData(:,:,1))));
```

fre: 20Hz to 1MHz
HData is complex number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

easy workaround:

```
x = 1:30;
y = log(x);
figure
hold on
rectangle('Position',[0 min(y) 10 max(y)],'FaceColor','g')
rectangle('Position',[10 min(y) 10 max(y)],'FaceColor','b')
rectangle('Position',[20 min(y) 10 max(y)],'FaceColor','r')
semilogx(x,y,'k');
hold off
```

Have a look at the rectangle function [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html#f66-515573-pos).

The position of the rectangle is determined by a 4 element vector `[x y width height]` where `x` and `y` is the lower left edge of the rectangle

Comment: Hi; Thanks for your kind reply. It works for me. but consider my plot is like bode plot and its y axis have negative and positive values in dB and rectangle function does not work for negative values.

Comment: I'm sure it should work but you have to adjust the y position and the height of the rectangle accordingly

Comment: I cannot test it right now but try something like '[0 min(y) 10 max(y)-min(y)]' for the position